Define an infinite sequence starting from behind.
I am working on a measure theory problem, but I am struggling with defining a certain exhausting sequence.
Given the set $\mathcal{F} = \{\{n, n+1, n+2, \dots\}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, I want to show that there exists an exhausting sequence $(G_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{F}$ such that $G_{n} \uparrow \mathbb{N}$. \
\noindent My idea went as follows. Define $G_{n} = \{n, n+1, n+2, \dots\}$. Then $\dots \supset G_{3} \supset G_{2} \supset G_{1}$. I want to define a sequence such that $G_{1}$ is the last element, and "$G_{\#\mathbb{N}}$" is the first one, so basically, in sloppy notation: 
\begin{align*}
H_{n} := G_{\#\mathbb{N} - n}
\end{align*}.
I have no idea how I can define these sets $H_{n}$ such that the notation is correct, and I am not using $\#\mathbb{N}$ as a subscript. This gives rise to two questions for me:

Can you speak of the existence of a sequence if there is no way to define it?
If this sequence exists, how do I define/reorder it in this case?

Thank you very much in advance.

I don't understand the problem. Does the sequence $(G_1, G_1, G_1, …)$ not do what you want since $G_1 = ℕ$? If not, please define what you mean by an exhausting sequence. NB: Your inclusions are backwards: $G_1 ⊃ G_2 ⊃ G_3 ⊃ …$.
